# Yii2 Attempt to read property "id" on int

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

I tried implementing Transactions using example below on Yii2 inside my Model class.

```
    <php
    $transaction = $connection->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $user_model=$connection->createCommand()
                ->insert('tbl_user', [
                        'name' => 'yii',
                        'status' => 1,
                ])->execute();

        $connection->createCommand()
                ->insert('tbl_user_roles', [
                    'role' = "admin",
                    'user_id'= $user_model->id
                ])->execute();
        //.....
        $transaction->commit();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        $transaction->rollback();
    }
?>
```

But I keep getting error:

```
Attempt to read property "id" on int on this line:
'user_id'= $user_model->id
```

When I remove the second createCommand, the user insert works, so nothing wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Method [`yii\db\Command::execute()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-command#execute()-detail) doesn't return model. It returns `int` representing the number of rows affected by executed query.

So, if you do

```php
$user_model=$connection->createCommand()
    ->insert('tbl_user', [
        'name' => 'yii',
        'status' => 1,
    ])->execute();
```

Then the value in `$user_model` variable is most likely `1`. And of course you can't do `1->id`.

To get the ID of the new user you have to call [`yii\db\Connection::getLastInsertID()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-connection#getLastInsertID()-detail).

For example like this:

```php
$transaction = $connection->beginTransaction();
try {
    $connection->createCommand()
         ->insert('tbl_user', [
             'name' => 'yii',
             'status' => 1,
         ])->execute();
    $userId = $connection->getLastInsertID();
    $connection->createCommand()
        ->insert('tbl_user_roles', [
            'role' = "admin",
            'user_id'= $userId
        ])->execute();
    //...
    $transaction->commit();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $transaction->rollback();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, very well explained. But will getLastInsertID() return the ID of that specific execute? Or will it return the last ID from the DB? In other words if another had to execute after my execute, will it return my ID or will it return the ID of the one after?

If it returns the ID of the one after, how can I change it to make absolutely sure I get my ID back for the User I inserted?

Comment: `getLastInsertID()` returns the id from most recent `INSERT` on per-connection basis. So, simply calling it right after executing insert as I did in the example should be enough.